# Is it possible to use widgets in a GWT ToggleButton?

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I would like to know if it is somehow possible to use widgets in a ToggleButton, because I have an image on the downFace of a ToggleButton and want to use the Image widget, so that I can define a resource property.

Code looks like this (or should look like this, doesn't work of course):

```
<g:ToggleButton addStyleNames="{res.css.button} {res.css.active} {style.inventory-button}">
    <g:upFace>upFace Text</g:upFace>
    <g:downFace>downFace Text <g:Image resource="{res.wantedImage}" addStyleNames="{res.css.load}"></g:Image></g:downFace>
</g:ToggleButton>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ToggleButton`'s `g:downFace` takes an `ImageResource` as an `image=` attribute:

– Source: http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/CustomButton.html

But you cannot use both an image and text that way.

AFAICT, you can however use an image and text through HTML (but without widget):

```
<g:downFace>downFace Text <img src="{res.wantedImage.getSafeUri}" /></g:downFace>
```

or through a `@sprite` in a `CssResource`:

```
<g:downFace>downFace Text <span class="{res.css.wantedImageAsSprite}"></span></g:downFace>
```

Comment: Thank you! The first way doesn't work, the src attribute in the compiled code is "#" for some reason. But the second way does, even though it's not that beautiful ^^ But it works, that's what's important (:

Comment: Ah yes, try `getSafeUri` without the `asString` (you should have had a warning about `SafeUri` I suppose)